# Hidden files and folders are hidden / ignored in wildmenu

Tags: autocompletion, wildmenu

As mentioned, when using `<TAB>` completion, hidden files do not show up.
E.g. `:e <TAB>` only shows non-hidden files.

```
:verbose set wildignore?
  wildignore=
```

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122136/autocomplete-hidden-files-in-vim), while an unanswered one is [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22036/autocomplete-hidden-files). Obviously both didn't help me.

How to debug this?
How do I display hidden files/folders when using tab?

Comment: If I hit `.<Tab>`, I get hidden files (`.<C-d>` too)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble this also lists hidden files for me. However, I want hidden files to show up next to non hidden ones when using `<TAB>` alone.

Answer (score 4):

Hidden files do not automatically show up in wildcard expansions unless there's a leading dot, but this behavior can be switched on in the source code.

Let's dive in. `src/vim.h` defines a number of flags that determine how wildcard expansions are to be performed. [One of them](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2c70711e3fb2ef24a7f55322fdadbf7f9e657c2f/src/filepath.c#L3718) is `EW_DODOT`, which [if set](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2c70711e3fb2ef24a7f55322fdadbf7f9e657c2f/src/filepath.c#L3718) will cause wildcard expansions to pick up dot files automatically.

Looking at the latest version of the code with `git grep EW_DODOT`, nowhere in the code does there occur any setting of the `EW_DODOT` flag. The flags are initially set [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2c70711e3fb2ef24a7f55322fdadbf7f9e657c2f/src/cmdexpand.c#L1938) in `ExpandFromContext()` in `src/cmdexpand.c` and if you set it by adding `flags |= EW_DODOT` and recompile vim it will expand dot files by default. You can confirm it by either `:e <tab>` or `:echo expand('*')` in a directory that contains hidden files.

If it were to become a configurable option, it would probably appear in [this list](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2c70711e3fb2ef24a7f55322fdadbf7f9e657c2f/src/cmdexpand.c#L267). The options listed there [take effect](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2c70711e3fb2ef24a7f55322fdadbf7f9e657c2f/src/cmdexpand.c#L1939) in `ExpandFromContext()` by having respective flags set based on them.

Searching back through the history for changes involving `EW_DODOT` by running `git log -GEW_DODOT`, it looks like the `EW_DODOT` internal flag was introduced in commit [b0967d58](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b0967d587fc420fa02832533d4915c85d1a78c17) (which was vim release 7.4.1116) and was at that time [used in a call](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b0967d587fc420fa02832533d4915c85d1a78c17/src/fileio.c#L7316) to `gen_expand_wildcards()`, but only when invoking `delete_recursive()` to recursively delete a directory tree. All uses of this flag were [completely discarded](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/701ff0a3e53d253d7300c385e582659bbff7860d#diff-d63764951497182a8a3fd237136b91a72d4b68b1ab264919aa86abd840f26984L7202) with a major code change in commit 701ff0a3 with a new implementation of recursive file removal. We can confirm that even at that point the `EW_DODOT` flag [was not](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/701ff0a3e53d253d7300c385e582659bbff7860d/src/ex_getln.c#L5018) set dynamically like some of the others in `ExpandFromContext()`, so this internal feature simply got buried.

Comment: Thanks. To briefly sum up, currently this is not possible without building `vim` from source. Do you have any idea about `nvim`?

Comment: Let's check the source code.

Comment: For others coming here and wondering: After briefly looking into the source code of nvim, I think something similar is true. It appears that the flags and and functions are named the same but filenames are different. In any case the flag `EW_DODOT` is also not set in `ExpandFromContext()`.